# What does "have a catch" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning, idiom-meaning

The context of this phrase is following: "I am happy to have a catch with you to discuss this in more detail."

Comment: It means your interlocutor is not a native speaker of English. His first language is something other than English. Other than that, he's happy to *catch up* with you to discuss <whatever topic> in more detail.

Answer (score 4):

My suspicion is that your conversation partner wants to have a *catch-up*, rather than a *catch*, i.e. a conversation in which you *[catch up](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=catch)*:

> 4. To bring (another) up to date; brief
>
>    > *Let me catch you up on all the gossip.*

[AHD] While this sense does not seem to be found in dictionaries, examples abound online, e.g. [“we have a catch up with Neil Hamilton”](http://www.belfasttelegraph.co.uk/life/features/the-conversation-we-have-a-catch-up-with-neil-hamilton-31127924.html) or [“after the game I'm sure we'll have a catch up and a bit of a yarn”](http://www.stuff.co.nz/sport/rugby/all-blacks/73471525/australianborn-all-black-tawera-kerrbarlow-puts-perspective-on-transtasman-rivalry-ahead-of-world-cup-final).

---

But if they did indeed say *have a catch*, it is a metaphorical usage.

To *have a catch* is to *play catch* or to *have a game of gatch*, in the first noun definition of *[catch](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=catch)* as given by AHD:

> 1b. A game of throwing and catching a ball.

In my personal experience, the phrasing *have a catch* is mostly Northeastern, though I cannot present evidence that it is a regionalism.

The archetypical game of catch, for Americans, is a father and son tossing a baseball back and forth— providing an excuse to spend time together and have a conversation. Thus, the teary closing lines of the 1988 film *Field of Dreams*:

> Ray: Hey... Dad? You wanna have a catch?
>   John: I'd like that

Thus, *if* the other party does want to *have a catch* with you, it means they want to do some activity together where you can have a conversation, perhaps because conversation by itself would be less worthy of time, or perhaps awkward.